# ggplot2: Map create with several elements is not saved in the image

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, r-sf

I'd like to create a map in `ggplot2` with my target coordinates, the north arrow and scale bar for example, but despite the `ggsave()` function saving the last plot, it doesn't work in `mymap.png` image.
In my example:

```
#Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsn)

# Get data set - x any are the points
all.stands.predict<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/prediction__bug_2021-03-18.csv")
all.stands.predict<-all.stands.predict[all.stands.predict[,3]=="VILA PALMA",] # Area selection

#Create a map
gg <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=all.stands.predict, 
  aes(x=x, y=y), color="red") +
  xlab("Latitude") + ylab("Longitude") +
  theme_bw() 

#Add a scale bar.
gg <- gg + scalebar(location="bottomright",y.min=max(all.stands.predict$y)-0.001, y.max=max(all.stands.predict$y), 
             x.min=max(all.stands.predict$x)-0.001, x.max=max(all.stands.predict$y), model='WGS84',
             transform=TRUE)
#

#Add a north arrow
north2(gg, 0.85, 0.85, symbol = 10)

#Save image in png
ggsave("mymap.png", dpi=300, width = 20, height = 20)   
#
```

When I inspected my "mymap.png" image created, just the north arrow is represented and looks like this:

[image: mymap.png]

Please, any ideas for saved all the map elements?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are just adding the symbol then use `north` with `data=NULL` like this
`gg + north(...)`. May this help, I would try out some example map when time allow.

Comment: Thanks but not work, the output is: `#Add a north arrow
gg+north(data=NULL, 0.85, 0.85, symbol = 10)
Error in north(data = NULL, 0.85, 0.85, symbol = 10) : 
  argumento "x.min" ausente, sem padrão`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is possible with the `ggspatial` package:

```
#Packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)
library(sf)

# Get data set - x any are the points
all.stands.predict<-read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/prediction__bug_2021-03-18.csv")
all.stands.predict<-all.stands.predict[all.stands.predict[,3]=="VILA PALMA",] # Area selection

#Create a map
(sites <- st_as_sf(all.stands.predict, coords = c("x", "y"), 
                   crs = 4326, agr = "constant"))
gg <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=sites, color="red") +
  annotation_north_arrow(location = "bl", which_north = "true", 
                         pad_x = unit(0.3, "in"), pad_y = unit(0.5, "in"),
                         style = north_arrow_fancy_orienteering) + #Add a north arrow
  annotation_scale(location = "bl", width_hint = 0.55) + #Add a scale bar
  xlab("Latitude") + ylab("Longitude") +
  theme_bw() 
plot(gg)
ggsave("mymap.png", dpi=300, width = 20, height = 20)
```